# Which protocol does WCF Test Client use (WcfTestClient.exe) to get metadata

Tags: wcf

According to my understanding metadata can be explored by using three types of bindings:

```
mexHttpBinding
mexHttpsBinding
mexTcpBinding
```

Are all these bindings supported by `WcfTestClient.exe` ?

UPD

According to my understanding alternative way to get metadata is get WSDL information (old way of posting metadata).

If `EcfTestClient.exe` supports all these bindings listed above it don't need `WSDL`. According to my understanding to enable `WSDL` I need to place  `<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"  />` in web.config in `behaviors`. This is not required if metadata is retrieved using `mexHttpBinding,mexHttpsBinding,mexTcpBinding` bindings. Please, correct me if I'm wrong. In this case `WcfTestClient.exe` finds metadata.

If I do false for both `httpGetEnabled` and `httpsGetEnabled` `WcfTestClient.exe` can't get service info:

```
Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from http://localhost:35168/mySrv.svc If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address.
```

Looks `WcfTestClient.exe` is getting information from WSDL and not from bindings     `mexHttpBinding , mexHttpsBinding , mexTcpBinding`?

Answer (score 0):

Well, based on MSDN, WCFTestClient supports all the bindings supported by SvcUtil. Now, if you look at the excerpts from MSDN below:

Svcutil issues the following metadata requests simultaneously to retrieve metadata.

MEX (WS-Transfer) request to the supplied address

MEX request to the supplied address with /mex appended

DISCO request (using the DiscoveryClientProtocol from ASMX) to the supplied address.

Looks like its safe to assume that WcfTestClient supports all three for metadata download.

[MSDN WCFTestClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364(v=vs.110).aspx)

[MSDN SvcUtil](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: But according my experiments described in message body UPD section looks like WCFTestClient uses only old WSDL way?